# Heroku Git Bash issue while commit 2 and 3 for discord hosting shows this message: On branch mymaster nothing to commit, working tree clean

Tags: git, heroku, gitlab, hosting

The first command I enter is `git commit -am "First commit"`, which works out alright.

Git two and three however don't work and show the following message response:

```
On branch mymaster nothing to commit, working tree clean.
```

I know this has something to do with `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your `git status` output

A [`git commit -am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--a) would add only modified or deleted files: *not* new files.

Try instead:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add files"
```